# Flutter dropdown menu not changing state

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

Can someone please help me solve the problem with the change state in the dropdown menu?
The item does not change when I select the a menu. it remains on index[0].

```
class RegionalDailyTableStats extends StatefulWidget {
  
  final String getString;
  final String getBargraphString;
  final String getAreagraphString;
  final String getGraphString;
  final String getLineGraphString;
  final String getPDFString;
  final String getPieChartString;
  const RegionalDailyTableStats({
    super.key,
   
    required this.getString,
    required this.getBargraphString,
    required this.getAreagraphString,
    required this.getGraphString,
    required this.getLineGraphString,
    required this.getPDFString,
    required this.getPieChartString,
  });

  @override
  State<RegionalDailyTableStats> createState() =>
      _RegionalDailyTableStatsState();
}

class _RegionalDailyTableStatsState extends State<RegionalDailyTableStats> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    List<String> graphs = [
      widget.getGraphString,
      widget.getBargraphString,
      widget.getAreagraphString,
      widget.getLineGraphString,
      widget.getPieChartString,
    ];
    String? selectedGraph = graphs[0];

    return Container(
      height: screenHeight,
      width: screenWidth,
      
      child: SizedBox(
                 width: screenWidth * 0.1,
                 child: Column(
                    children: [
                              DropdownButton<String>(
                                  value: selectedGraph,
                                  items: graphs.map((e) {
                                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                                      value: e,
                                      child: Text(e),
                                    );
                                  }).toList(),
                                  onChanged: (val) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      val = selectedGraph;
                                    });
                                  }),
                            ],
                          )
                      );
              }
           }
```

I have edited the code. Please take a look at it. This is the full code for what I wanted to do. But it's still not working

Comment: make sure to put `String? selectedGraph = widget.getGraphString;` outside the build method

Comment: I have edited the code. Please take a look at it for me

Comment: `String? selectedGraph = graphs[0];` outside the build method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be initalising variables within the build method of your code. Build methods run everytime the screen is refreshed, so even if you fixed the assignment issue that other people have pointed out

```dart
onChanged: (val) {
   setState(() {
       selectedGraph = val; 
   });
})
```

The build method would be called again to run `selectedGraph = graphs[0]`.

To properly initalise the state, use the StatefulWidget's `initState()` method.

```dart
class _RegionalDailyTableStatsState extends State<RegionalDailyTableStats> {
  late List<String> graphs;
  late String? selectedGraph;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    graphs = [
      widget.getGraphString,
      widget.getBargraphString,
      widget.getAreagraphString,
      widget.getLineGraphString,
      widget.getPieChartString,
    ];
    selectedGraph = graphs[0];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Container(
      height: screenHeight,
      width: screenWidth,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: screenWidth * 0.1,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            DropdownButton<String>(
                value: selectedGraph,
                items: graphs.map((e) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: e,
                    child: Text(e),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedGraph = val;
                  });
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code lies within the onChanged callback of your dropdown button. You're assigning the value of selectedGraph to value, instead of assigning value to selectedGraph.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RegionalDailyTableStats extends StatefulWidget {
  final String getString;
  final String getBargraphString;
  final String getAreagraphString;
  final String getGraphString;
  final String getLineGraphString;
  final String getPDFString;
  final String getPieChartString;

  const RegionalDailyTableStats({
    required this.getString,
    required this.getBargraphString,
    required this.getAreagraphString,
    required this.getGraphString,
    required this.getLineGraphString,
    required this.getPDFString,
    required this.getPieChartString,
  });

  @override
  State<RegionalDailyTableStats> createState() =>
      _RegionalDailyTableStatsState();
}

class _RegionalDailyTableStatsState extends State<RegionalDailyTableStats> {
  late String selectedGraph;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedGraph = widget.getGraphString;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    List<String> graphs = [
      widget.getGraphString,
      widget.getBargraphString,
      widget.getAreagraphString,
      widget.getLineGraphString,
      widget.getPieChartString,
    ];

    return Container(
      height: screenHeight,
      width: screenWidth,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: screenWidth * 0.1,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            DropdownButton<String>(
              value: selectedGraph,
              items: graphs.map((e) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: e,
                  child: Text(e),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedGraph = val!;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RegionalDailyTableStats(
          getString: 'String',
          getBargraphString: 'Bar',
          getAreagraphString: 'Area',
          getGraphString: 'Graph',
          getLineGraphString: 'Line Graph',
          getPDFString: 'PDF',
          getPieChartString: 'Pie Chart',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}
```

Answer (score -3):

On your setState method inside OnChange.
Invert val = selectedGraph, like below

```
onChanged: (val) {
    setState(() {
      selectedGraph = val;
   });
})
```

Comment: I have done that, but it's still not working

Comment: Like Josia mendes mentionned it, you should initialise your value and list inside the InitState() method, because everytime you select an item, the widget rebuild, this is why it always stays on graphs[0]